# SYMFONY ORM Как запретить инверсные значения

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine2, symfony3

В чём собственно вопрос - есть такая таблица:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
*/        
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
*/
private $name;
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
*/
private $slug;
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="id")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)
*/
private $parent;

public function __toString() {
    return (String) $this->getParent();
}

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="category", cascade={"persist"})
*/ 
private $posts;

public function __construct() {
    $this->posts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Есть ли какой-то уже готовый способ в `ORM` или в `SYMFONY` чтобы при добавлении данных в таблицу нельзя было сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или же нужно самому перед добавлением данных делать проверку?

Буду очень благодарен за ответы! Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

На уровне маппинга или схемы БД это не запретить. Проверяйте отношения между сущностями на этапе [валидации](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).